# mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: Failed executing the operation;

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python

I am trying to insert near 40 thousand row with "mycursor.executemany(sql, data_list)" and getting error given below in "mycursor.executemany(sql, data_list)" this line. i am using mysql-connector-python=8.2.0,  python=3.11 and VPS machine= Alma-liux 8.8.

```
  File "/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor_cext.py", line 406, in _batch_insert
    raise InterfaceError(f"Failed executing the operation; {err}") from None
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: Failed executing the operation;
```

i am using mysql-connector-python=8.2.0,  python=3.11 and VPS machine= Alma-liux 8.8.

This is code of insert

```
sql = f"""INSERT INTO {website} ({columns}) VALUES ({placeholders});"""
        mycursor.executemany(sql, data_not_present)
        mydb.commit()
```

This is the error after tacking some time

```
  File "/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor_cext.py", line 406, in _batch_insert
    raise InterfaceError(f"Failed executing the operation; {err}") from None
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: Failed executing the operation;
```